# Orthocentr and circumcentre formula in 3D

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given three points in a 3D coordinate system, how can we find the orthocentre and circumcentre of the triangle formed by these points?

Comment: But this is in 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given three Points: $$P,Q,R$$
Calculate:
$$\begin{array}{l}
{M_{PQ}} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {P + Q} \right)\\
{M_{QR}} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {Q + R} \right)\\
{M_{RP}} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {R + P} \right)
\end{array}$$
and solve
$$P + r \cdot {M_{QR}} = Q + s \cdot {M_{RP}}$$
for circumcentre.
With
$$\begin{array}{l}
u = \overrightarrow {PQ}  = Q - P\\
v = \overrightarrow {PR}  = R - P\\
{u^ \bot } = u - \frac{{u \cdot v}}{{v \cdot v}}v
\end{array}$$
and
$$\begin{array}{l}
a = \overrightarrow {QR}  = R - Q\\
b = \overrightarrow {QP}  = P - Q\\
{a^ \bot } = a - \frac{{a \cdot b}}{{b \cdot b}}b
\end{array}$$
solve:
$${M_{PQ}} + r \cdot {u^ \bot } = {M_{QR}} + s \cdot {a^ \bot }$$
for
orthocentre.